# Where Python's execv implementation is located?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to find where in CPython's implementation `execv` is implemented. I've found [this](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/e65cce5eec23812d77a54095209c923937cc3c92) commit from Guido where he adds it back in 1993, but the commit does not show where `execv` comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `help(os.execv)`:

> Help on built-in function execv in module posix:

> execv(path, argv, /)
> Execute an executable path with arguments, replacing current process.

> ```
> path
>   Path of executable file.
> argv
>   Tuple or list of strings.
> ```

It's defined in `posix`, which is a c module to wrap unix functions. The snippet you are probably looking for is [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/posixmodule.c#L5789):

```c
#ifdef HAVE_EXECV
/*[clinic input]
os.execv
    path: path_t
        Path of executable file.
    argv: object
        Tuple or list of strings.
    /
Execute an executable path with arguments, replacing current process.
[clinic start generated code]*/

static PyObject *
os_execv_impl(PyObject *module, path_t *path, PyObject *argv)
/*[clinic end generated code: output=3b52fec34cd0dafd input=9bac31efae07dac7]*/
{
    EXECV_CHAR **argvlist;
    Py_ssize_t argc;

    /* execv has two arguments: (path, argv), where
       argv is a list or tuple of strings. */

    if (!PyList_Check(argv) && !PyTuple_Check(argv)) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError,
                        "execv() arg 2 must be a tuple or list");
        return NULL;
    }
    argc = PySequence_Size(argv);
    if (argc < 1) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError, "execv() arg 2 must not be empty");
        return NULL;
    }

    argvlist = parse_arglist(argv, &argc);
    if (argvlist == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    if (!argvlist[0][0]) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError,
            "execv() arg 2 first element cannot be empty");
        free_string_array(argvlist, argc);
        return NULL;
    }

    if (PySys_Audit("os.exec", "OOO", path->object, argv, Py_None) < 0) {
        free_string_array(argvlist, argc);
        return NULL;
    }

    _Py_BEGIN_SUPPRESS_IPH
#ifdef HAVE_WEXECV
    _wexecv(path->wide, argvlist);
#else
    execv(path->narrow, argvlist);
#endif
    _Py_END_SUPPRESS_IPH

    /* If we get here it's definitely an error */

    free_string_array(argvlist, argc);
    return posix_error();
}
```

Comment: Just a quick follow up question before marking as accepted, do you know where `execv` goes right after the `#else` macro in that snippet? Thanks, that's exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @luizbarcelos Unfortunately, my c is not great. Best I can tell is that if `HAVE_WEXECV` or `HAVE_EXECV` is defined, then python is being used [within the windows runtime](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/posixmodule.c#L306) and only certain unix functions may be available and a wrapper is explicitly defined. Otherwise, `os` can just directly call into the `execv` function due to [clinic](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/clinic.html) generating the boilerplate. My understanding here is pretty thin, so take this comment with a hefty pinch of salt